# LINQ expression with multiple methods

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the following code and I'm not able to understand why it returns only two elements instead all. It looks like "Where" method works only with last added method.

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static bool IsAdult(Person person)
    {
        return person.Age > 18;
    }

    public static bool MethodTrue(Person person)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person() { Age = 20, Name = "Artur" },
            new Person() { Age = 30, Name = "Adam" },
            new Person() { Age = 10, Name = "Wieslaw" },
            new Person() { Age = 15, Name = "Michal" }
        };


        Func<Person, bool> predicate = null;
        predicate += MethodTrue;
        predicate += IsAdult;

        var res = list.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect to get all four `Person` objects when only two of the four meet the criteria defined by your predicate? How many of the objects do you expect `IsAdult()` to return `true` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you concatenate delegates this way, all of them will be executed, but you will get result only from the **last** one.
See hier about this using of delegates:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

*If the delegate has a return value and/or out parameters, it returns the return value and parameters of the **last** method invoked.*

Reverse order will give you all results:

```
Func<Person, bool> predicate = null;
predicate += IsAdult;
predicate += MethodTrue;
```

But i don't see any sense in doing linq this way. You could just write

```
Func<Person, bool> predicate = x=> IsAdult(x) || MethodTrue(x);
```

Or `&&`  , it depends on what do you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Having it put in reverse order will only be a band aid fix.  If logic is added to the MethodTrue that filters out there, it will cause the same problem.  The only reason reversing them will work is because that method always posts true.  The true fix is getting down to what logical comparison you want to do.

Comment: Well done. The reference to MSDN is the key here. Very interesting behavior.

Comment: Agreed, MSDN article spells it out nicely, concatenating methods with the `+=` is not the way to go, unless you only want the final result set of the last evaluated method, which why bother with the other methods then.

Answer (score 2):

The way you've chained the two predicates, it only cares about the last one (the second one here).

Even if that was not the case, `MethodTrue()` always returns true and only two of the persons pass the criteria of `IsAdult` that's why it only returns two items. By the way, you don't really need the `predicate` variable. You could write something like this:

```
var res = list.Where(p => MethodTrue(p) && (IsAdult(p)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resulting set is being filtering out based on your predicate.  You have your predicate defined as: `IsAdult` which will do the age comparison **AND** `MethodTrue` which will always return true.  So if the persons age fails the `age > 18` check, then your where statement fails on that item in your list.

So your where clause will only return 2 values because only 2 people are adults according to your logic in your `IsAdult` function.

**Result based on predicate:**

```
var list = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person() { Age = 20, Name = "Artur" },
        new Person() { Age = 30, Name = "Adam" }
    };
```

If you are looking to do an `or (||)` statement, you can write your predicate as followed to return all values as Maksim Simkin mentioned.

```
 Func<Person, bool> predicate = x => IsAdult(x) || MethodTrue(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

When you provide two functions in your predicate, they are evaluated with the bitwise `AND (&&)` which means that only objects that both functions return are included. Since you're filtering out `Person` objects 18 and younger with `IsAdult()` only two records are returned from that function. That means that the bitwise operation will never return more than those two records.

Comment: both are executed, but only result of the last one is returned, reverse order will return all 4 person.

Comment: Interesting - it appears to be an issue related to the way the `+=` operator is applied for functions. As mentioned in other answers, `Func<Person, bool> predicate = x => MethodTrue(x) && IsAdult(x);` returns the two records as I'd expect.

Comment: @RickLiddle No, it's not about how delegates are combined, it's about the behavior of invoking a delegate with multiple methods in the invocation list, and how it determines what value to return in such a situation.